# HTML / CSS float left doesn't work on my code

Tags: html, css

I am currently teaching myself HTML / CSS. After some tutorials I am now building my first own project. I try to structure three images and three texts on my page using CSS.

The structure should look like this:

```
Text - Image
Image - Text
Text - Image.
```

I tried to position the images with float: right and float: left respectively. But all three images are positioned on the right again and again.

Can you help me? Thank you very much.

```html
<div class="Food">
  <div>
    <p class="Foodtext">
      fvjkhfhikvfdhilvdlhifbikfddbuukubfkuvbduhvdjhvdfkuvhukufvhjkdfuubfdkuhvhukvvhukfdubbf
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src=speise.jpg alt="Speise" style="float: right">
  </div>
</div>
<h3>Wine</h3>
<div class="Wine">
  <p class="Winetext">
    fhkvbshukveuvbkdfjvbuvfdsfkufbekfbgkrbkfewrrkgbgburfbuehu
  </p>
</div>
<div>
  <img src="wein.jpg" alt="Weinregal" style="float: left">
</div>
</div>
<h3>Music</h3>
<div class="Music">
  <div>
    <p class="Musictext"> vbhuireeehugoreiur8hgeoirorguuhghirruhgfuhkgrhukge</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="dj.jpg" alt="DJ legt auf" style="float: right">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _"But all three images are positioned on the right again and again."_ - what are you talking about? The images themselves are missing when the snippet here gets executed - put the placeholders clearly are aligned right, left, right.

Comment: Also, fix your HTML structure. `.Wine` is missing an opening `div` tag before `.Winetext`.

Answer (score 2):

You've floated your images *inside* divs, by themselves. That's like trying to move to the right inside your clothing. Floated images should have the same parent as the content you want to flow around them.

So just combine the divs. You may even want your images inside the paragraphs.

Also, be sure to use a good editor (or at least run your code through an HTML validator). Either will make structural and semantic mistakes obvious.

```html
<div class="Food">
  <div>
    <p class="Foodtext">
      fvjkhfhikvfdhilvdlhifbikfddbuukubfkuvbduhvdjhvdfkuvhukufvhjkdfuubfdkuhvhukvvhukfdubbf
    </p>

    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="Speise" style="float: right">
  </div>
</div>

<h3>Wine</h3>

<div class="Wine">
  <p class="Winetext">
    fhkvbshukveuvbkdfjvbuvfdsfkufbekfbgkrbkfewrrkgbgburfbuehu
  </p>

  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="Weinregal" style="float: left">
</div>

<h3>Music</h3>

<div class="Music">
  <div>
    <p class="Musictext"> vbhuireeehugoreiur8hgeoirorguuhghirruhgfuhkgrhukge</p>

    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="DJ legt auf" style="float: right">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This example `That's like trying to move to the right inside your clothing` was very good :)))

Comment: Not should the second text be placed on the right side of the second image? Since the second image has `float: left. (Or for the first case, the image to be on the right side of the text) It seems a little disordered!!

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are styling the image while your image resides inside a new div.

Try this code instead

```
<div class="Food">
  <div>
    <p class="Foodtext">
      fvjkhfhikvfdhilvdlhifbikfddbuukubfkuvbduhvdjhvdfkuvhukufvhjkdfuubfdkuhvhukvvhukfdubbf
    </p>
  </div>
  <div style="float: right">
    <img src=speise.jpg alt="Speise">
  </div>
</div>
<h3>Wine</h3>
<div class="Wine">
  <p class="Winetext">
    fhkvbshukveuvbkdfjvbuvfdsfkufbekfbgkrbkfewrrkgbgburfbuehu
  </p>
</div>
<div style="float: left">
  <img src="wein.jpg" alt="Weinregal">
</div>
</div>
<h3>Music</h3>
<div class="Music">
  <div>
    <p class="Musictext"> vbhuireeehugoreiur8hgeoirorguuhghirruhgfuhkgrhukge</p>
  </div>
  <div style="float: right">
    <img src="dj.jpg" alt="DJ legt auf">
  </div>
</div>
```

do this and it should work you might need to specify the max-width of the divs as well and apply 100% width to the image in case you apply max-width, rest this should be working!